# New lines in word definition using interpreter directives of Gforth

Tags: forth, gforth

I am using the interpreter directives (non ANS standard) control structures of Gforth as described in the manual section [5.13.4 Interpreter Directives](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Interpreter-Directives.html). I basically want to use the loop words to create a dynamically sized word containing literals. I came up with this definition for example:

```
: foo
   [ 10 ] [FOR]
      1
   [NEXT]
   ;
```

Yet this produces an *Address alignment exception* after the `[FOR]` (yes, I know you should not use a for loop in Forth at all. This is just for an easy example).

In the end it turned out that you have to write loops as one-liners in order to ensure their correct execution. So doing

```
: foo [ 10 [FOR] ] 1 [ [NEXT] ] ;
```

instead works as intended. Running `see foo` yields:

```
: foo  
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ; ok
```

which is exactly what I want.

Is there a way to get new lines in the word definition? The words I would like to write are way more complex, and for a presentation I would need them better formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would really be best to use an immediate word instead. For example,

```
: ones ( n -- ) 0 ?do 1 postpone literal loop ; immediate
: foo ( -- ten ones )  [ 10 ] ones ;
```

With `SEE FOO` resulting in the same as your example.  With `POSTPONE`, especially with Gforth's `]] .. [[` syntax, the repeated code can be as elaborate as you like.

A multiline `[FOR]` would need to do four things:

1. Use `REFILL` to read in subsequent lines.
2. Save the read-in lines, because you'll need to evaluate them one by one to preserve line-expecting parsing behavior (such as from comments: `\` ).
3. Stop reading in lines, and loop, when you match the terminating `[NEXT]`.
4. Take care to leave >IN right after the `[NEXT]` so that interpretation can continue normally.

You might still run into issues with some code, like code checking `SOURCE-ID`.

For an example of using REFILL to parse across multiple lines, here's code from [a recent posting from CLF](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.forth/YVjtNQwSIH0/Qtld--7vtuoJ), by Gerry:

```
: line,  ( u1 caddr2 u2 -- u3 )
    tuck here swap chars dup allot move +
; 

: <text>  ( "text" -- caddr u )
    here 0
    begin
        refill
    while
        bl word count s" </text>" compare
    while
        0 >in ! source line, bl c, 1+
    repeat then
;
```

This collects everything between `<text>` and a `</text>` that's on its own line, as with a HERE document, while also adding spaces. To save the individual lines for `[FOR]` in an easy way, I'd recommend leaving 0 as a sentinel on the data stack and then drop `SAVE-MEM` 'd lines on top of it.